# Selecting a linked excel chart in powerpoint

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint, paste

I have a powerpoint presentation with 100 slides and most of them have linked excel charts.  I am trying to run a macro that will cycle through the slides and then the shapes on the slides and find the linked chart/graph, copy it, and paste it into the same position as a metafile so that I can make an emailable pdf file.  However, the macro is skipping over the chart or not recognizing it as a chart.  I searched and searched, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Select_All()
    Dim oPresentation As Presentation
    Set oPresentation = ActivePresentation

    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oSlides As SlideRange
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim slideNumber As Integer
    Dim shapeNumber As Integer
    Dim lastslideNumber As Integer
    Dim lastshapeNumber As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim w As Double
    Dim h As Double
    Dim l As Double
    Dim t As Double

    For slideNumber = 14 To 100

        oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Select

        For i = 1 To oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes.Count
            If oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes(i).HasChart Then
                oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes(i).Select
                oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes(i).Copy
                With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
                    w = .Width
                    h = .Height
                    l = .Left
                    t = .Top
                End With
                oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes(i).Delete
                oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)

                With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
                    '.Width = w
                    '.Height = h
                    .Left = l
                    .Top = t
                    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
                End With
            End If

        Next i

    Next slideNumber

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be cleaner but you can save the copy/paste step if you simply ungroup the chart shape.  That'll give you a metafile directly.

```
Sub Select_All() 
Dim oPresentation As Presentation 
Set oPresentation = ActivePresentation

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oSlides As SlideRange
Dim oShape As Shape
' These should be Longs
Dim slideNumber As Long
Dim shapeNumber As Long
Dim lastslideNumber As Long
Dim lastshapeNumber As Long 
Dim i As Long

Dim w As Double
Dim h As Double
Dim l As Double
Dim t As Double

For slideNumber = 14 To 100

    'oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Select
    ' never select anything unless you absolutely must
    Set oSlide = oPresentation.Slides(slidenumber)

    For i = oSlide.Shapes.Count to 1 step -1
    ' Step through shapes backward, else you'll run into weird 
    ' side effects when deleting shapes
        If oSlide.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
            'oPresentation.Slides(slideNumber).Shapes(i).Select
            ' don't select anything etc etc
            oSlide.Shapes(i).Copy
            With oSlide.Shapes(i)
                w = .Width
                h = .Height
                l = .Left
                t = .Top
          End With
          oSlide.Shapes(i).Delete
          set oShape = oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

            With oShape
                '.Width = w
                '.Height = h
                .Left = l
                .Top = t
                .ZOrder msoSendToBack
            End With
        End If

    Next i

Next slideNumber
```